How to find the value of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$?
How to find the value of $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$?
We all know that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$.
But how to prove it? This is my doubt.
We all are familiar with the Maclaurin series expansion of $\sin(x)$, which is
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}- \frac{x^{7}}{7!}+O(x^{8}).$$
Now, I want the value of $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$
So, as a student of Mathematics what I will do is that I will substitute $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$
That is I will get the series to be somewhat like
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^{3}}{2^{3}×3!}+\frac{\pi^{5}}{2^{5}×5!}- 
\frac{\pi^{7}}{2^{7}×7!} +O(x^{8})$$
I just wrote $O(x^{8})$ for the sake of convenience. Because actually the $\sin(x)$ series is an infinite series. But it is not possible for anyone to write a series upto infinity.
So, I applied the concept of Big-O notation.
Now this is an infinite summation. And in this infinite summation it is clear to me that the common ratio is $-\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}$. Because if we divide the $(n+1)^{th}$ term by the $(n)^{th}$ term, then I will get the common ratio to be $-\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}$.
Just note that $n\geq 1$.
Also please note that I just mentioned the common ratio concept just for identifying. Though it is of no use here specially for this question.
Therefore we can say that the summation can be written like this
$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\pi^{n}}{2^{n}×n!}$.
But how to find the value of this infinite summation ? Is there any way for this? Also I want to know that whether the summation $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\pi^{n}}{2^{n}×n!}$ will converge or diverge?
Because before finding the summation, we need to check the convergence of the series first.

This really depends on how $\sin, \cos, \pi$ are defined. For example, one can define $\sin$ and $\cos$ via the series and then define $\pi$ as the smallest positive solution of $\cos(x) =0$, multiplied with $2$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\pi^{n}}{2^{n}×n!}=1-e^{-\pi/2}\ne\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$

$\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^{3}}{2^{3}×3!}+\frac{\pi^{5}}{2^{5}×5!}-
\frac{\pi^{7}}{2^{7}×7!} +O(x^{8})$ makes no sense. Anyway, an approximation won't ever give you the exact value.

It is not clear what you mean by "the common ratio is $\frac{-\pi^{2}}{4}$".

Please edit your post to include your definition of $\sin$.

The simplest way to find the value of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{2n+1}$$ is to note that this equals to $\sin\frac\pi2=1$.

@AnneBauval, I just mentioned that the common ratio is $-\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}$. Actually I needed the method for solving the summation.

This comment doesn't clarify anything to me. What "common ratio?" What method for "solving" (=?) what summation? Please edit your post to fix each of the 4 problems pointed in comments 8 hours ago.

Edited @AnneBauval. Please clarify once. Hope now you will understand what I am trying to say.

Again: $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\ne\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\pi^{n}}{2^{n}×n!}$. And $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}- \frac{x^{7}}{7!}+O(x^{8})$ is true (but useless for an exact evaluation of $\sin(\pi/2)$), whereas $\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^{3}}{2^{3}×3!}+\frac{\pi^{5}}{2^{5}×5!}-  \frac{\pi^{7}}{2^{7}×7!} +O(x^{8})$ is not even false. And your series is not geometric, so there is no "common ratio" (you are forgetting the factorials). And you still didn't include your definition of $\sin$. (By the way, your definition of $\pi$ is also necessary.)

Ok. I actually misunderstood the concept of common ratio. Yes now I understood the actual fact Anne Madam . I totally got confused with the concept of Geometric series with this $\sin(x)$ series.  Thank you Anne Madam for helping me out. Really very much thank you for figuring out my mistake.

Why the downvote ? Please allow me to delete this question. If a question gets downvoted even after showing the Approach then please delete the question.

Perhaps use the relation $\cos(\alpha) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)$.  (Since "co" sine means sine of the complementary angle.) Then take $\alpha=0$ to get $\cos(0) = \sin\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Then the question is: $\cos(0) = 1$.  For that we can easily use the Maclaurin series of $\cos x$.

Finding the Maclaurin series of $\cos x$ won't be too different from the original question if the definition of $\cos x$ is $\sin(\pi/2 - x)$.
